# What is wrong with this dynamic code execution?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
var code = @"public class Abc { public string Get() { return ""aaaaaaaaaa""; }}";
var options = new CompilerParameters();
options.GenerateExecutable = false;
options.GenerateInMemory = false;

var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var compile = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, code);

var type = compile.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Abc");
var abc = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

var method = type.GetMethod("Get");
var result = method.Invoke(abc, null);
ut = result.ToString();
```

the variable *code* in this case gets executed correctly, but if I do something different like:

```
var code = @"using System; public class Abc { static string Get() { return System.DateTime.Now}}";
```

It does not get executed and gives me the following error: *Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\TEMP\504kbl2w.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified*

Why does it happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: You have `private` (no modifier specified) static method with return type `string`, but your method returns `DateTime` type (not `string`).  You can write `regular` code first with class declaration with one method, when your code works then you can copy it to string.

Comment: Also you may missed the semicolon";" at the end of your return line.

Comment: I'm an idiot, i'm blind... ahahah *facepalm*. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code fails / can't be compiled because it contains three issues:

1. The method needs to be public
2. The return value is not a `string` like specified
3. Missing semicolon in the method

Fix it like this to get it running:

```
var code = @"using System; public class Abc { public static string Get() { return System.DateTime.Now.ToString(); } }";
```

You should check the errors after compiling your code [compile.Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.compilerresults.errors?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).

Comment: As I said to the other guys, I'm blind! ahah by the way, thanks!

Comment: Just to know, is there any alternative to this code I posted? I mean, is there anyway to execode code in a dynamic way without writing a DLL?

Comment: You can use ```GenerateInMemory = true```

Comment: Seems like it still writes a dll file. If I give on purpose in input a code that does not work, the error remains the same: [FileNotFoundException]: Could not load file or assembly &#39;file:///C:\Windows\TEMP\djalepia.dll&#39; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: A file can also be created just in memory. So this is not necessarily a "file" on your storage.

Comment: Understood, thanks for your help! I really appreciate!